# Xampp suddenly requesting 32bit libs

Tags: xampp

Xampp was working **perfectly** until yesterday. but now it tells me:

> XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a
>   32 bit compatibility library for your system.

This is very strange, because it was working without problems. I don't know exactly what happened! Anyway, I was about to install 32bit libs but found them **no longer available**.

Something maybe related to the issue, today I was trying to install composer dependency manager but failed. Also yesterday I did semi update to my system.

- Ubuntu 14.4 64 bit
- Xampp 1.8.3-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAMPP is a *toy* version of the `lamp-server^` task.

I can see some benefits on systems where LAMP is harder to set up but seriously, you can't convince me that playing around with a non-production system is going to beat developing on what's likely to be your production environment.

Even if you aren't considering running it in a production role, the production bullet in the [LAMPP Linux FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html) *should* be enough to terrify you into not using it.

My advice is to remove XAMPP and run:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin php5-gd
```

You'll end up with a system that is used on thousands (possibly millions) of servers and it'll give you a good jump on server administration.

---

Failing that, it seems like you've installed the 32bit version. You could mess around fulfilling the dependencies manually (beugh) or you could just download the 64bit version from [the XAMPP download page](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

Comment: the current version is already 64bit and it was working. i tried to install it again but still see the same error. thank you for the moving to lamp advice i will consider that.